# How can I solve `Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.` in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have below code in `Flutter` to use `graphql` library:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';

var httpLink = HttpLink(
  'https://api.github.com/graphql',
);

var authLink = AuthLink(
  getToken: () => 'Bearer <YOUR_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN>',
);

final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
  GraphQLClient(
    link: link,
    // The default store is the InMemoryStore, which does NOT persist to disk
    cache: GraphQLCache(store: HiveStore()),
  ),
);

const provider = GraphQLProvider(
  client: client,
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'demo',
  ),
);
```

There is a compile error on the line `client: client`:

```
Const variables must be initialized with a constant value.
Try changing the initializer to be a constant expression
```

Why does it compliant about `const`? Does it relate to the library?

Answer (score 3):

It complain because the const must be initialized with a constant value which is not in your case.
As client can be anything at runtime. So you can't do this.

```
provider = GraphQLProvider(
  client: client,
  child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'demo',
  ),
);
```

Choices

1. Replace client with some const value or make client itself a const.
2. You can make provider final .

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

```
const provider
```

to

```
final provider
```

Method 2:

to

```
const provider = const GraphQLProvider(...)
```

but I am afraid that class does not support

Notice that const and final are very **different in Dart(Flutter)**.